# Is there any simple "one click" solution to clear print queue in KDE?

Tags: kubuntu, printing, kde

my old grandpa (born 1929) uses Kubuntu for surfing and some basic tasks. He is often behaving chaotically and for example he easily fills print queue with several tasks and then struggles to get rid of them.

Is there any simple solution how to remove all print tasks from the queue without need to go through System settings?

He has only one printer (HP LaserJet 1200) so could be something to remove all tasks for all printers and could be a shell script also as I could create him a shortcut - desktop icon to click on.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is. Read `man cancel;man lprm` :  `lprm -a` should do the trick.

Comment: thanks. Desktop shortcut with "lprm -" command worked for me. Great.